# what do I use for model and controller with Facebook's React and ES6

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm a noob on react/es6 stack/framework. I was previously developing in Backbone/Marionette.js and recently started reading more about ES6 and React. Considering my background I'm used to having Backbone for Model and Controller (MC of MVC pattern). I have heard people using react with Backbone/Ember/Angular. What are your experiences and what are the different patterns that are trending in this area at the moment. I'll really appreciate you sharing your experiences/thoughts on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want to look into flux

Comment: possible duplicate of [React is V, how about the M and C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427788/react-is-v-how-about-the-m-and-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook has proposed the Flux architecture as a way of flowing data unidirectionally into your React components. The idea is that you have a separate container (often called a "store") for all of your data. You register actions which run through a dispatcher and change your data, which then causes your view components to update.

There have been a lot of implementations of this idea. So far there isn't a single plug and play data model that's a no-brainer to use.

One implementation that has a lot of people excited right now is called [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux). Like React, it draws inspiration from the functional programming school of thought.

From the README:

> The whole state of your app is stored in an object tree inside a single *store*.
>
> The only way to change the state tree is to emit an *action*, an object describing what happened.
>
> To specify how the actions transform the state tree, you write pure *reducers*.

So it's not exactly the MVC paradigm, but when combined with React you have a chain of events where the user triggers some action which changes the data and updates the view.

I recommend checking out the examples in the repo. It's a solid approach that's gaining a lot of traction. It also comes with a really neat dev tools. Hopefully in the future someone will be able to abstract away more of the boilerplate code.

Comment: I can only speak for Redux, but it's definitely worth looking into. Since you write the reducer functions as pure functions (no side effects, just return new instance of state), you get nice things for free like time travel debugging (undo/redo), hot reloading (live updates), and the ability to serialize your entire app state. http://merrickchristensen.com/articles/single-state-tree.html